# UPDATE SQL by DAO in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

The query below works in SQL server

```
UPDATE PriceGroupDetail SET Status = 'h'
FROM PriceGroupDetail INNER JOIN PriceGroup
ON PriceGroupDetail.[_FID_Group] = PriceGroup.[_ID]
WHERE PriceGroup.[Group] = 'Dealer'
```

But, I run it in Access 2013 VBA code.  error message is "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression".  The DBSQL is project global variable and connects to SQL server.

```
DBSQL.Execute "UPDATE PriceGroupDetail SET Status = 'h' " & _
     "FROM PriceGroupDetail INNER JOIN PriceGroup " & _
     "ON PriceGroupDetail.[_FID_Group] = PriceGroup.[_ID] " & _
     "WHERE PriceGroup.[Group] = 'Dealer'"
```

Comment: You could run it as a pass-thru...  this way it accepts (and expects) the native DBMS SQL

Comment: Set dbSQL = OpenDatabase("", False, False, "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" & _
 "Server=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DB1; Trusted_Connection=yes;")

Comment: Thank you Hambone,  yes pass-through works.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in Access SQL there is no UPDATE ... FROM ...

Correct syntax would be:

```
UPDATE PriceGroupDetail INNER JOIN PriceGroup
    ON PriceGroupDetail.[_FID_Group] = PriceGroup.[_ID]
SET PriceGroupDetail.Status = 'h'
WHERE PriceGroup.[Group] = 'Dealer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with pass-through.  semicolon is not required.

```
DBSQL.Execute "UPDATE PriceGroupDetail SET Status = 'h' " & _
     "FROM PriceGroupDetail INNER JOIN PriceGroup " & _
     "ON PriceGroupDetail.[_FID_Group] = PriceGroup.[_ID] " & _
     "WHERE PriceGroup.[Group] = 'Dealer'", dbSQLPassThrough
```